# Cannot update or remove iCal events with PHP

Tags: php, gmail, icalendar

I am really struggling with removing or updating iCal events.  Its easy to invite someone to an event, but once they have accepted it, it cannot be changed.  Any attempt to update or remove/cancel the event from their calendar does not work.  Updating with a new address just adds a new event, and leaves the old one.  I am using the same UID, upping the Sequence number by one, and getting a banner on Gmail saying that the event has been cancelled - but alas, it is not.

I have been trying to figure this out for the last two days, but there are very few resources on the web relating to iCal events, and they seem very finicky to work with.

Below is the code I currently have, which gmail says has cancelled the event - but its a lie:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
STATUS:CANCELLED
ORGANIZER:'.$from_address.'
ATTENDEE:'.$client_email.'
DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
DTEND:'.$dtend.'
LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
SEQUENCE:1
UID:'.$cal_uid.'
DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
SUMMARY:'.$client_subject.'
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Please, if you can solve my problem, I will be eternally grateful

Comment: Please provide both the original invitation (REQUEST) and the CANCEL corresponding to an actual interaction (i.e. not some pseudo code).